# Why am I getting TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'tuple'?

Tags: python, loops, variables, pygame, runtime-error

I need help with a `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'tuple'` error in line 158

The program is basicly a game in pygame where you shoot at objects coming towards you (this is pretty much irrelevant, but if anyone wants to be able to understand the variables I think it can help).

The problem is located in the main loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
while run:
    last = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == my_event_id:
            x = random.randrange(screen_width - 64 * 2)
            index = random.choice(number)
            asteroids_on_screen.append(Enemy((x, rock.y), rock.width, rock.height))

    for a in asteroids_on_screen:
        if 0 < a.y < 500: # right here is the error
            a.y -= a.vel
        else:
            asteroids_on_screen.pop(asteroids_on_screen.index(a))
```

Here is the full code if you want to see all the details.

```
import pygame

import random

pygame.init()

screen_width = 500
screen_height = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
walk_left = [pygame.image.load('sprite_5.png'), pygame.image.load('sprite_6.png')]
walk_right = [pygame.image.load('sprite_3.png'), pygame.image.load('sprite_4.png')]
standing = [pygame.image.load('sprite_0.png'), pygame.image.load('sprite_1.png'), pygame.image.load('sprite_2.png')]


class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 4
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.standing = True
        self.walk_count = 0
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 2, self.y + 26, 123, 45)

    def draw(self, win):
        if self.walk_count + 1 >= 12:
            self.walk_count = 0

        if not self.standing:
            if self.left:
                win.blit(walk_left[self.walk_count // 6], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walk_count += 1
            elif self.right:
                win.blit(walk_right[self.walk_count // 6], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walk_count += 1
        else:
            win.blit(standing[self.walk_count // 4], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walk_count += 1
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 2, self.y + 31, 123, 40)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 2)


def move():
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.vel or keys[pygame.K_a] and man.x > man.vel:
        man.x -= man.vel
        man.left = True
        man.right = False
        man.standing = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.width - man.vel:
        man.x += man.vel
        man.left = False
        man.right = True
        man.standing = False

    else:
        man.standing = True


class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, y, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 1.5
        self.y = y
        x = random.randrange(screen_width - 64 * 2)
        self.hitbox = (x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

    def draw(self, win):
        if index == 0:
            self.hitbox = (x + 68, self.y + 68, self.width - 10, self.height - 14)
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 2)
        elif index == 1:
            self.hitbox = (x + 38, self.y + 47, self.width + 20, self.height - 5)
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 2)
        elif index == 2:
            self.hitbox = (x + 18, self.y + 12, self.width + 32, self.height + 30)
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 2)
        elif index == 3:
            self.hitbox = (x + 20, self.y + 32, self.width + 16, self.height + 5)
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 2)
        else:
            self.hitbox = (x + 4, self.y + 7, self.width - 24, self.height - 31)
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 2)


my_event_id = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(my_event_id, 1000)


class Projectile:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.vel = 5

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.height, self. width))


class Unit:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.cooldown = 200

    def fire(self):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last >= self.cooldown:
            self.last = now
            spawn_bullet()


def spawn_bullet():
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        bullets.append(Projectile((man.x + 126 // 2), (man.y + 5), 7, 3, (255, 0, 0)))


def re_draw():
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    man.draw(win)
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(win)
    for a in asteroids_on_screen:
        a.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()


asteroids = [pygame.image.load('rock0.png'), pygame.image.load('rock1.png'), pygame.image.load('rock2.png'),
             pygame.image.load('rock3.png'), pygame.image.load('rock4.png')]

number = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

delay = Unit()
man = Player(186, 400, 128, 128)
bullets = []
asteroids_on_screen = []
rock = Enemy(10, 64, 64)

run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while run:
    last = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == my_event_id:
            x = random.randrange(screen_width - 64 * 2)
            index = random.choice(number)
            asteroids_on_screen.append(Enemy((x, rock.y), rock.width, rock.height))

    for a in asteroids_on_screen:
        if 0 < a.y < 500:
            a.y -= a.vel
        else:
            asteroids_on_screen.pop(asteroids_on_screen.index(a))

    for bullet in bullets:
        if 0 < bullet.y < 500:
            bullet.y -= bullet.vel
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    move()
    delay.fire()
    clock.tick(60)
    re_draw()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please share which line of code produces the error

Comment: Also, see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57688653/if-row-1-or-column-1-typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-tup?rq=1

Comment: @ItamarMushkin The error occurs in line 158

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Enemy` initializer: `def __init__(self, y, width, height)`

You passed: `Enemy((x, rock.y), rock.width, rock.height))`

So your `enemy.y` is actually a tuple of `(x, rock.y)`. Surely you can't compare this with an `int`.

Next time, print out the things you are comparing and bugs like this will be obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused, because the first parameter to the constructor of `Enemy` has to be a single y coordiante:

> ```py
> class Enemy:
>    def __init__(self, y, width, height)
>        # [...]
>        self.y = y
> ```

But when you crate the `Enemy` object, then the 1st parameter is a tuple (`(x, rock.y)`):

> ```py
> asteroids_on_screen.append(Enemy((x, rock.y), rock.width, rock.height))
> ```

So `a.y` is a tuple rather than a single value. Probably it has to be:

```py
asteroids_on_screen.append(Enemy(rock.y, rock.width, rock.height))
```